# write! macro does not work properly with async function in Rust

Tags: rust, async-await, io, rust-tokio

Here's a simplified version of my funciton:

```rust
async fn show_status(root_dir: &PathBuf, mut output: impl std::io::Write) -> Result<(), Error> {
    writeln!(output, "status:");

    let mut commponent_ids = walk_components(&StatusVisitor::new(), &root_dir, None).await?;
    writeln!(output, "ids: {:?}", commponent_ids);
    output.flush();

    Ok(())
}
```

And this is my test case:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::show_status;

    #[tokio::test]
    async fn test_show_status() {
        let mut output = Vec::new();
        show_status(&main_repo_dir, &mut output).await;

        assert_eq!(std::str::from_utf8(output.as_slice()).unwrap(), "status:\nids: [0, 1]");
    }
}
```

I think the case may pass as expected, but the fact is that I got following failure:

```bash
assertion `left == right` failed
  left: "status:\n"
 right: "status:\nids: [0, 1]\n"
```

I have no idea why the second line can not be seen in the output. Can anyone give me some help?

I have asked chatgpt and it told me to use the traits `tokio::io::AsyncWriteExt` instead of `std::io::Write`. But when I tried the solution, nothing changed.

I have also tried that call the funciton in main funciton directly instead of calling it in a testcase. Unexpectedly, I works properly. I saw both 2 lines in the stdout.

So my problem is: What happened with the testcase? Why can't I seen the second line in the output in a async testcase?

Comment: Looks like `walk_components` errors and the function returns early before the second `writeln!`, maybe? You should check what `show_status` returns. This should have nothing to do with `async`.

Comment: I asked chatgpt again, and I got a new answer. I seems to explain what's my problem is:
From the code you provided, it seems like the function `show_status` is an asynchronous function, and you're not properly awaiting it in your test case. This could be the cause of the problem you're experiencing.

In Rust, when calling an async function, you need to use the `.await` keyword to wait for the function to complete. If you don't use `.await`, the function will return immediately with a future, and the actual computation will not be performed.

Comment: @jianliangwang the answer chatgpt is bullshit with respect to your issue (or at least with respect to the code you have posted).

Comment: Please create a [mre] as pointed out the problem might be `walk_components` errors, but you don't show it's implementation.

Comment: @jthulhu I adopt chatgpt's suggestion, and the testcase suprisingly passed. As chatgpt said, I changed the following line:
 ```show_status(&main_repo_dir, &mut output).await; ```
to this: ```show_status(&main_repo_dir, &mut output).await.unwrap();```Judging from the results, what he said seems to make sense.

Comment: I don't believe adding `unwrap()` fixed the problem (also, it was not ChatGPT's suggestion).